# map <expr> <F2> Cannot Check Focus Pane

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, functions

## How can a keypress dynamically change its behavior, depending upon which split pane has focus?

(Specifically, whether the pane containing the cursor has another split pane to the right, or not.)

`map <expr>` Can be used to map the keypress to the result of an expression, such as:

```
noremap <expr> <F2> RightPane() ? ':echom RightPane()' : 'Never happens'
```

But the rightmost result is **never** returned! When <kbd>F2</kbd> is pressed with the cursor/focus in the left split pane:

- the expression `:echom RightPane()` is displayed in the status bar.
- Pressing <kbd>CR</kbd> then always evaluates properly, as either 0 or 1.
- 'Never happens' is never shown, however

#### Can the function respond differently, based on the pane with the cursor, each time <kbd>F2</kbd> is pressed?

The function is defined as follows:

```
func! RightPane()    
  let saveW = winnr() 
  silent! exe "normal! \<c-w>l"
  let rightW = winnr()
  silent! exe saveW.'wincmd w'
  return saveW == rightW
endfunction
```

---

### Example Use-Case

#### Resize Panes Using Ctrl-Arrow Keys:

```
func! RightPane()    
  let saveW = winnr() 
  exe "normal! \<c-w>l"
  let rightW = winnr()
  exe saveW.'wincmd w'
  return saveW == rightW
endfunction

" Resize split panes using Ctrl-Arrow
noremap <expr> <C-Left>  RightPane() ? '<C-W>>' : '<C-W><'
noremap <expr> <C-Right> RightPane() ? '<C-W><' : '<C-W>>'
noremap <expr> <C-Up>    BottomPane() ? '<C-W>+' : '<C-W>-'
noremap <expr> <C-Down>  BottomPane() ? '<C-W>-' : '<C-W>+'
```

Comment: Why `== 0` ? That seems redundant. Also I feel like there may be missing `<CR>`s there. None of this explains the behavior though. Unless the entire expr needs quoted?

Comment: The `== 0` is a vestige of debugging, trying several different expressions in searching for the issue. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `map-<expr>` the allowed actions are limited. You explicitly suppressed error messages with `silent!`. If you remove this, you get the error message:

```
Error detected while processing function RightPane:
line    2:
E523: Not allowed here
```

Using `:normal` is not allowed in a `map-<expr>`. See `:help map-<expr>`.

BTW: You could replace that with `wincmd l`, but that isn't allowed either.

Note that the second call to `RightPane()` is not within the context of `map-<expr>`, so it returns the expected value.

---

Update: You could work with a "normal" map, like:

```
function! DoVertResize(left, right)
    if RightPane()
        execute "normal \<C-W>" . a:right
    else
        execute "normal \<C-W>" . a:left
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-Right> :call DoVertResize('>','<')<CR>
nnoremap <C-Left> :call DoVertResize('<','>')<CR>
```

Comment: Excellent insight. The map <expr> *is* being re-evaluated each time (but is hitting errors).

Comment: I've clarified the question. Is it impossible?

Comment: @BrentFaust See my latest update

Comment: Nice! Or, the one-liner: `execute "normal \<C-W>" . (RightPane() ? a:right : a:left)`